# Calling function with callback in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am stucking with this code.
I need to check if a token is ok before proceed to a an "api" route.
My problem is my callback in the line

```
checkTokenAlive(token, function (err) {
```

never returns.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
....
checkTokenAlive = (decoded, cb) => {
    const now = Date.now().valueOf() / 1000
    if (typeof decoded.exp !== 'undefined' && decoded.exp < now) {
        cb(`token expired: ${JSON.stringify(decoded)}`)
    }
    if (typeof decoded.nbf !== 'undefined' && decoded.nbf > now) {
        cb(`token not yet valid: ${JSON.stringify(decoded)}`)
    }
}
checkTokenAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.body.token;
    checkTokenAlive(token, function (err) {

       console.log('I am here');  //problem - never called
       if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.status(400).end(err)
        }
        return next()
    });
}

app.post('/api', checkTokenAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    ....
})
```

Comment: Well, if both `decoded.exp` and `decoded.nbf` are `undefined` or have certain values then you never call your callback.  And, since those values come from `req.body` which can contain anything from an incoming request, that is clearly a problem.  Also, it appears that you don't call the callback when the token is still valid.

Comment: I think, your both if condition `if (typeof decoded.exp !== 'undefined' && decoded.exp < now) {` and `if (typeof decoded.nbf !== 'undefined' && decoded.nbf > now)` inside `checkTokenAlive` function  are evaluated to false. So, it never reaches cb

Comment: Hi, Thank you friends. It was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your logic is flawed in `checkTokenAlive()` because you may never call the callback under some conditions (like when the token is valid) and you could even call it twice.   I don't know exactly what all the conditions should be, but here's one idea:

```
checkTokenAlive = (decoded, cb) => {
    const now = Date.now().valueOf() / 1000;
    if (!decoded || typeof decoded.exp !== "number" || typeof decoded.nbf !== number") {
        cb(`invalid or missing token`);
    } else if (decoded.exp < now) {
        cb(`token expired: ${JSON.stringify(decoded)}`)
    } else if (decoded.nbf > now) {
        cb(`token not yet valid: ${JSON.stringify(decoded)}`)
    } else {
        // token looks good
        cb();
    }
}
```